# How to check, is function argument type is equal to one of the custom interfaces?

Tags: typescript

My interfaces:

```
interface ClientHeightEventHandlerType{
    (event: {clientHeight: number}): void;
}

interface ClientWidthEventHandlerType{
    (event: {clientWidth: number}): void;
}
```

A list of overloads:

```
subscribe( handler: ClientHeightEventHandlerType ): void;

subscribe( handler: ClientWidthEventHandlerType  ): void;
```

Function were I need to check is function argument is equal to one of the interfaces:

```
subscribe(handler: any  /**callback function*/): void {


   //How to check, is 'handler' argument type is equal to 
   //ClientHeightEventHandlerType or ClientWidthEventHandlerType
   //...


}
```

How to make this check?
I tried guards already, but as I understood they wouldn't help me in this case.

Comment: There's no way to check that in runtime. Both "types" are just functions. You can, of course, take the `.toString()` of the functions and do a string comparison but I strongly advise against that. Why do you care which one of the two it is?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Based on type knowledge and using if() statement program will deside were to subscribe handler.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I was trying to simplify my code example, before asking. I'm sorry that the purpose of method is unclear.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Is that what you meant?

Comment: The structure of `ClientHeightEventHandlerType` and `ClientWidthEventHandlerType` are same -- the only difference is the parameter names. I am not what you can achieve by differentiating between the two.

Comment: @Saravana hmm... I just wanted to control, that I will pass right function to the right Publisher (Observer pattern), and I thought that 'checking function type' is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `any`.
Your signature should look like this:

```
subscribe(handler: (event: {clientHeight: number} | {clientWidth: number}) => void): void {
    ...
}
```

The more intuitive signature:

```
subscribe(handler: ClientHeightEventHandlerType | ClientWidthEventHandlerType): void
```

Won't work because then the compiler will complain when you try to invoke the `handler` function with this error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type 'ClientHeightEventHandlerType | ClientWidthEventHandlerType' has no
>   compatible call signatures.

---

#### Edit

You cannot differentiate between those two types at runtime.
What you can do is:

(1) Add a "type" to the interface:

```
interface ClientHeightEventHandlerType {
    type: "ClientHeightEventHandlerType";
    handler: (event: {clientHeight: number}) => void;
}

interface ClientWidthEventHandlerType {
    type: "ClientWidthEventHandlerType";
    handler: (event: {clientWidth: number}) => void;
}
```

And then use a type guard to check which has been passed.

(2) Add a type to the function:

```
subscribe(type: "ClientHeightEventHandlerType", handler: ClientHeightEventHandlerType): void;
subscribe(type: "ClientWidthEventHandlerType", handler: ClientWidthEventHandlerType): void;
subscribe(type: "ClientHeightEventHandlerType" | "ClientWidthEventHandlerType", handler: (event: {clientHeight: number} | {clientWidth: number}) => void): void {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get how you were planing to check type of the handler inside function. As I understand this syntax just gives opportunity to pass to function different handlers (now we can control them) but as I see it doesn't give opportunity to identify them inside function.

Comment: I used 'any' type , based on an example with 'function overload' that were given on the TypeScript official site: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: That's look like a TypeScript life huck ;) But as I understand that's the one possible way to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Not typescript specific. It's the same for js